# Create SVG in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, svg

It looks like there is a wealth of SVG parsers out there. Has anyone written a SVG generator for Objective-c? I have point data (ideally bezier data) that I want to write out to SVG. If you know of an example or library to do this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write CGPathRef data (bezierPath.CGPath) to SVG file using [MROGeometry library](https://github.com/mro/MROGeometry)